# sweetalert 2 target a div rather than entire window?

Tags: sweetalert

Is it possible to target a div rather than the entire window for [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io)?

If not is is possible to edit the center coordinates?

The reason I ask is that I have a few JavaScript games that i would like to use this framework with. these are loaded in `<div>`'s  which are not centered on the page. The sweet alert popup looks strange when it opens as it is miss-aligned.

This is fine for mobile games but not for browser based.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'I will be placed inside the #swal2-container',
  target: document.getElementById('swal2-container')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<div id="swal2-container"></div>
```

SweetAlert2 documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply limote.
Its a great library by the way, please dont take my questions as a bad thing :)

Comment: I have just seen that you updated this, thank you :)

Comment: One issue... Sorry... I have updated using the code above and now the positioning is broken. Is there an email i can reach you on to show you the issue?

Comment: Thanks!!!! This helped me A LOT to solve a problem with fullscreen and conflicts between Swal and Bootstrap Modal