# Sweet alert 2 - position swal in middle of a div

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I need to position a Swal in the middle of a div.
According the documentation:
https://sweetalert2.github.io/

it can be done with "target" param but It's not working for me.

I have prepared the following JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue:

```
swal({
      title: 'Hello',
      target: ".myClass"
        });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utpgoL49/14/)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sweetalert 2 target a div rather than entire window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788590/sweetalert-2-target-a-div-rather-than-entire-window)

Answer (score 4):

The target param needs to be used with document.getElementById('myDiv') rather than ".myClass"

```
swal({
    title: 'Hello',
    target: document.getElementById('myDiv')
});
```

All the target param does is let you determine which div or element the sweetalert2 div gets appended to. The default is <body> but if you specify a div, you will still get a full screen overlay, the code is simply appended into the div of your choice.

As a work around you could provide some override CSS in your style sheet:

```
#myDiv .swal2-container {
    position:inherit;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}

<div class="myClass" id="myDiv"></div>
```

But this will only work if your div is empty, as soon as you put anything in the div, the alert will be offset underneath any content.