# SweetAlert 2 inside iframe - positioning and options

Tags: jquery, iframe, sweetalert2

Ok so i'm using an iframe to a page that has SweetAlert2 and a table. While clicking a button on the table it will return row information (such as title, region etc). Everything works as it should. SWAL2 is centered perfectly and all that.

My problem here is that i am also embedding that page into an iframe on a different page (lets call this parent page). This parent page is non-editable (no css, no JS, its a sharepoint modern page for whoever needs the info).

While clicking the button, SWAL2 will pop-up in the middle of the iframe and the user has to scroll down the table to get to the popup (or up, depending on where he was).

Is there any way to either make the popup show up on parent page (probably not since i can't add JS to it) or at least focus the iframe view on that pop-up on-click ? (something like using IDS and href's for links, #goto) ?

Any help would be appreciated (even a simple "not possible" so i dont waste even more time than i already did trying to find a way to do this).

Edit: Even tho' i don't need this anymore, this is not a duplicate. I mentioned i can't modify the parent page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sweet Alert 2 Open in Parent Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381063/sweet-alert-2-open-in-parent-frame)

Comment: Read the edit, not duplicate.